# Sending "null" through a variable on mysql won't delete the row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code/query:

```
if ($a == $b) {
    $type = 1;
} else {
    $type = null;
}

$this->query(
    'DELETE FROM users WHERE userid = ? AND type = ?',
    array($userid, $type)
);
```

Buy mysql doesn't understand the second case and won't delete the row if `$type` is `null`.

I know that a proper way to define null in a query would be with `IS NULL`, but in my case, it won't fit.

Can I somehow pass null through a variable?

Comment: Your query needs to be smarter and use IS NULL when appropriate

Comment: So it's better for me to use two queries under the if statement? (one with IS NULL and the other with $type?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly possible to make the `WHERE` clause itself aware switch between the value and `IS NULL` but requires additional conditions and additional placeholders.  In your case, since the query is simple, I would build it dynamically and append parameters to the `array()` for execution accordingly.

```
// The basic query, with conditions common to either case:
$sql = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE userid = ? AND ';

// For bound parameters...
// $userid will always be present
$params = array($userid);
if ($a == $b) {
  // Add an additional parameter for type
  $params[] = 1;
  // And add to the WHERE clause the type condition
  $sql .= ' type = ?';
}
else
  // Or the NULL  type condition
  $sql .= 'type IS NULL';
}
// Execute with the $params array, which has 1 or 2 elements.
$this->query($sql, $params);
```

In order to stuff this into one query, the `WHERE` clause would have to detect that the `type` variable was non-null with an `OR` condition. One way (not the only way, and maybe not the nicest way) to do it looks like this:

```
DELETE
FROM users
WHERE
  userid = ?
  AND ((? = 1 AND type = ?) OR type IS NULL)
```

In this case, the value of `$type` would be passed in twice, first to make the condition `1=1` true, then to actually compare with the `type` column.  But as you can see, when using placeholders, this becomes sort of confusing. It is easier to just build the string dynamically in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not understand `where columnname = null`. MySQL does understand `where columnname is null`

Try this:

```
if ($a == $b) {

    $this->query(
        'DELETE FROM users WHERE userid = ? AND type = ?',
        array($userid, 1)
    );
} else {
    $this->query(
        'DELETE FROM users WHERE userid = ? AND type IS NULL',
        array($userid)
    );
}
```

Comment: The OP always deserves more of an explanation than "try this".

Comment: Great point - you are 100% correct. I added a brief explanation to my answer. Also, thank you for responding to my request for an explanation!